# Marketing cloud journey entry criteria not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcedx, visual-workflow, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I'm using an "Action and Related Records" record-trigger flow (create) to update "MC_User_Journey" field. Based on that value I have created Entry criteria in the journey in my marketing cloud. Through flow, the field value was successfully updated and the criteria meet my journey entry criteria even though the record does not enter into the journey. But when I manually update the field value in the sales cloud it's entering into the journey as I expected. I don't know the exact reason why it's working like this. Could anyone explain me or is anyone facing this issue like me, if yes please help me to reach out to the solution.

I have attached some of my screenshots below, for reference. Thanks in advance

[image]
IMG 1.1 - flow entry type

[image: flow assignment image 2.png]

```
      IMG 1.2 - Flow value assignment
```

[image: update record flow 3.png]

```
         IMG 1.3 - Record Update
```

[image: confirmation update flow 4.png]

```
         IMG 1.4 - Confirmation value in salesforce record Details page
```

[image: marketing cloud journey entry flow 5.png]

```
    IMG 1.5 - Marketing cloud Entry criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an order of operations issue and there does not appear to control the order of of workflows that are run. The workflow that controls entry into the marketing cloud journey is running before this workflow.  You need to set the workflow to 'Fast Field Updates' rather than 'Actions and Related Records'